# Update individual values in duplicate rows

Tags: r

Suppose I have a dataframe that contains duplicate records:

## data

```
dt <- data.table(ID=c("A","A","B","B"),Amount1=c(100,200,300,400),
                 Amount2=c(1500,1500,2400,2400),Dupl=c(2,0,1,3))
```

the Dup1 column indicators how many duplicate rows I want. after duplicating I want to update The amount1 column value for the new row.

I started writing the code below, but don't know how to fully implement it

## result

```
rbind(dt,
      dt %>% 
        filter(Dupl > 0) %>% 
        mutate(Amount1=100))
```

The is the expected result, the value in Amount1has been updated by dividing the value of the previous row by 2

```
#   ID Amount1 Amount2 Dupl
#1:  A     100    1500    2
#2:  A     50     1500    2
#3:  A     200    1500    0
#4:  B     300    2400    1
#5:  B     400    2400    3
#6:  B     200    2400    3
#7:  B     100    2400    3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `rep`licate the sequence of rows by the 'Dupl' column to expand the dataset and then use `Reduce` to update the 'Amount1' column

```
library(data.table)
dt[, i1 := seq_len(.N)][rep(seq_len(.N), pmax(Dupl, 1))][, 
  Amount1 := Reduce(function(x, y) x/2, Amount1, accumulate = TRUE), 
     i1][, i1 := NULL][]
#   ID Amount1 Amount2 Dupl
#1:  A     100    1500    2
#2:  A      50    1500    2
#3:  A     200    1500    0
#4:  B     300    2400    1
#5:  B     400    2400    3
#6:  B     200    2400    3
#7:  B     100    2400    3
```

---

Or another option is to create a `seq`uence of multiples of 2 and divide the 'Amount1' for each 'i1'

```
dt[, i1 := seq_len(.N)][rep(seq_len(.N), pmax(Dupl, 1))][, 
    Amount1 := c(first(Amount1), Amount1[-1]/seq(2, 
           length.out = .N-1, by = 2)), i1][, i1 := NULL][]
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
dt %>%
   mutate(i1 = row_number()) %>%
   uncount(pmax(Dupl, 1)) %>%
   group_by(i1) %>% 
   mutate(Amount1 = accumulate(Amount1, ~ .x/2)) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   select(-i1)
# A tibble: 7 x 4
#  ID    Amount1 Amount2  Dupl
#  <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
#1 A         100    1500     2
#2 A          50    1500     2
#3 A         200    1500     0
#4 B         300    2400     1
#5 B         400    2400     3
#6 B         200    2400     3
#7 B         100    2400     3
```

Comment: Is it possible to change the values in the Amount1 column at the same time when the duplicate are created?

Comment: @capiono  Can you check my update?  Is that your expected output

Comment: @capiono  If you check my first two solution, it is doing the update by replicating the same row value

Comment: Thanks @arun for helping me with this. I have updated my question. I'm interested all the columns, but the value in Amount1 column needs to be updated in the new row by dividing the value of the previous row by 2